# Set axis in Google Earth Engine Chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart

I'd like to compare LAI (Leaf Area Index) data from the same region over different times using ui.Chart.image.series in Google Earth Engine.

I'm trying to set the axis to the same range, in order to compare the charts by using min Value and maxValue like this:

```
var chart2 =
    ui.Chart.image
        .series({
          imageCollection: lai_august_19_broadleaf,
          region: aoi,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500,
          xProperty: "system:index"
        })
        chart2.setOptions({
          title: 'Mean LAI France broadleaf forest forest June-August 2019',
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Time',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 6
          },
          vAxis: {
            title: 'LAI',
          },
        });
```

The chart however does not adjust the axis using that method. Is this the correct way or is there another one to adjust the axis?

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled across this; but is this working for you:

> hAxis: {
> title: 'Time',
> viewWindow: {minValue: 0, minValue: 6}
> }

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right, just missed some details. To set the min and max axis value you need to use the `viewWindow:{min: , max:}` dictionary inside the `hAxis` and `vAxis`, as follows:

```
var chart2 =
    ui.Chart.image
        .series({
          imageCollection: lai_august_19_broadleaf,
          region: aoi,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500,
          xProperty: "system:index"
        })
        chart2.setOptions({
          title: 'Mean LAI France broadleaf forest forest June-August 2019',
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Time',
            viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 6},
          },
          vAxis: {
            title: 'LAI',
            viewWindow: {min: 1, max: 7}
          },
        });
```